# how to dump a webservice xml

Tags: xml, web-services, weblogic, remote-debugging

could you suggest how can i dump an XML. I tried using tcpmon but it isn't not showing my xml request/response. my app is running externally in weblogic server at port 8001 and i am debugging it in eclipse using remote debugging hooking at port 5001.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Fiddler2 which solved my problems.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give [RESTClient](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/) a try.

Comment: for the environment configuration limitations, I can't use this one. I am currently using JAVA 5 (bea jrocket) and i can't configure java 6.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know tcpmon, but as far as I know, if the communication is on the same machine, you can't capture it using a sniffer (like WireShark).

I once used the [wsi-testing-tools](http://www.ws-i.org/deliverables/workinggroup.aspx?wg=testingtools) as a cheap solution for setting up a man-in-the-middle. 
You configure the wsi-testing-tools' monitor to listen on a certain port, and direct all your WS calls to this port. The monitor records all the requests and responses, and creates a nice formatted output that can be viewed in any browser.

(Please note that this is probably ***by far*** not the best solution. I had to use it due to draconian limitations on my tools selection, but it works)